# How do I delete spaces in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a panel with lots of `buttons` in different sizes in two columns
and I want it not to have spaces between the first button and the last button.
But I cannot seem to remove the autogenerated spaces.
You can see my code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/C7aQz

How to do it?

Comment: not link only the jsfiddle, show us some code and what you tried.

Comment: I think SO questions need code with jsFiddle! How can he post it directly? Moderators? :O

Comment: aboid inline styles ! please! :(

Comment: A hack. Yep you have code block and now it allows to put link to JSFiddle.

Comment: button { border: 0px; }

Comment: @Mohammad I guess, since `buttons` actually is code,  this might already work out to have "code" in your post.

Comment: :P oh yeah! @Christoph NICE dude :P

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
#panelTouchMenu {
font-size: 0;
}
button {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C7aQz/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use jQuery Masonry plugin to achieve this. This may be what you actually need.

Here is link to page with examples of Masonry usage: http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

There is no simple plain CSS solution for this that's why people invent such plugins.

Answer (score 0):

will [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C7aQz/3/) work for you ?

add a Css class for button

```
button{float:left;}
```